# My SQL case when not returning value on second column

Tags: mysql, pivot, case

It only returns value of EIA and not EIA 2

```
(
  case 
   when tc.name = 'EIA' then tor.value else null 
  end
) as EIA, 
(
  case 
   when tc.name = 'EIA 2' then tor.value else null 
  end
) as EIA2
```

This is this Table Structure

Test Performed          Tor Values
EIA, EIA 2              Positive, Positive

```
ID Name  EIA      EIA 2
1  John  POSITIVE no values??
```

Comment: did you tried else '' instead of null

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(
  CASE 
   WHEN tc.name IS NULL THEN '' WHEN tc.name = 'EIA' THEN tor.value
  END
) as EIA, 
(
  CASE 
   WHEN tc.name IS NULL THEN '' WHEN tc.name = 'EIA 2' THEN tor.value
  END
) as EIA2
```

Comment: it works on EIA but on EIA 2 the value is still null. I checked my database the EIA2 has a value, i dont understand why its like this btw the tor.value is concatenated `code`group_concat(tor.value SEPARATOR ', ')`code`

Comment: from where tor.values comes from?

Comment: i have test performed column then the next is tor values

Comment: i also added my full query.

Answer (score 0):

```
(CASE
      WHEN tc.name = 'EIA' THEN tor.value
      WHEN tc.name = 'EIA 2' THEN tor.value
      ELSE NULL
  END)
```

OR

```
(CASE
      WHEN tc.name = 'EIA' THEN tor.value
 END) as EIA,
(CASE WHEN tc.name = 'EIA 2' THEN tor.value
  END) as EIA2
```